# 2 colors in 1 textView

Tags: java, android

I know you can solve this with html like this:

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>1st</font> <font color=#ffcc00>2nd</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

But what if my text changes and is saved in a variable ?

Comment: errr, what variable ?

Comment: Why not use gradient instead ???

Answer (score 0):

Use **Graditent** instead .. Why to go to all this complication:

Define your gradient in your drawable-hdpi: graditent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient android:startColor="#333333" android:endColor="#404040"/> 
    <corners android:radius="100px"/>


</shape>
```

Then, use it in your layout like this:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:text="@string/heading"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#0099cc"
                android:typeface="normal" />
```

Better than all those complications in that variable.